# sending an entire string via Kafka producer

Tags: python, apache-kafka, sentiment-analysis

I am implementing a sentiment analyzer using tweets using Kafka as an initial step i am reading the tweets using tweepy API and then streaming it via kafka producer API.

find below my code for StreamListener class

```
class MyListener(StreamListener):
def __init__(self,api):
    self.api = api
    self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092')

def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        if "\"location\":null" not in data:
            self.producer.send('twitter',data)
            return True
    except BaseException as e:
        print(str(e))
        return False

def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
    return True
```

The part where I am stuck is I need to send the entire data. I am unable to do so, i am not sure if i have to convert it to a byte stream in order to send it as the kafka just transfers bytes of data.

Please let me know a way to transfer the entire data string as received.

Comment: My guess is that you need to specify a key_serializer. However, I am not sure cause I don't know this Python API.

Comment: "I am unable to do so" is not very precise. What's the error message you get?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I am trying to send the entire string but i am not receiving any data at the consumer end.

Comment: You will need to specify a string serializer in you producer config and string deserializer in you consumer config.